# Old Power Ranger like anime with transforming vehicles

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

At least 8 years ago, finding old *Power Ranger* like character where their vehicles transform while still riding ON their vehicle, red bike turns into a T-rex, yellow car turns into a rhino look alike, while in a later episode their spaceship turns into a dragon when red is controlling it. Totally not a transformer, looks like a Asians animation.

Comment: Your description is quite terse, could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 1):

#### [*Transformers: Rescue Bots*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2139371/)/[*Transformers: Rescue Bots Academy*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9557874/) (2011-2016)/(2019-)

The Autobots throughout the series gain the ability to turn into Dinobots. In the episode ["Quarry's Quarry"](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Quarry%27s_Quarry) they all eventually gain this ability. Bumblebee does turn up later in the series but I can't find an image of his Dinobot form.

[image: The Dinobots] [image: The Dinobots in the quarry]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Their spaceship is called "Sigma" and shows up a few times in the series.

[image: Sigma shown via a control panel]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The dragon episode sounds like ["The Mystery of Dragon Mountain"](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Mystery_of_Dragon_Mountain) where Heatwave, a red Autobot, controls a simulation for the recruits at a mountain with dragons.

[image: The Mystery of Dragon Mountain title card]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Sorry not this, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like D.I.C.E. (DNA Integrated Cybernetic Enterprises).

[image: DICE DVD]

TL;DR [here](https://youtu.be/1PlxLcv0ibo) is the trailer.

Made by Bandai it was originally broadcast on Cartoon Network in 2005.

It was later released in Japan as Dinobreakers.

The main character Jet (who wore the red armour) had a Dinobreaker (the machines the heros rode) which had a motorcycle and velociraptor mode.

Tak's (yellow) Dinobreaker was a car or a Dimetrodon.

Dinobreakers could change modes while being ridden.

I haven't watched many of the episodes, but there is a dragon ship in the [synopsis](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/D.I.C.E./Episodes!) of Season 2 Episode 2.